# SubVersion on Apache on Mountain Lion Server

Tags: macos, apache, svn, osx-mountain-lion

Not exactly a programming question but right now it's stopping me from programming.

Just migrated OSX Lion server to OSX ML server and most of my folders appear to have come back properly (via Migration Assistant) including the SubVersion repository but no matter how hard I try I can't get access to my SVN repository through Apache...

I've rebuilt the dav_svn_module and autz_svn_module and these are loading properly as per

> sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

```
..    
hfs_apple_module (shared) 
dav_svn_module (shared) 
authz_svn_module (shared)
```

I've setup my svn.conf file in the other folder in /etc/apache2/other which also gets loaded properly, I verify this using sudo apachectl -t and Apache reports "Syntax OK" at least.

My svn.conf file

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /opt/subversion/svnrepo/
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion"
  AuthUserFile /opt/subversion/conf/svn-auth-file
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

And yet whenever I try to access svn via http (i.e. http://server.mydomain.com/svn) I get a 404 error and the following in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file;

```
Fri Aug 16 15:25:41 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.50] File does not exist: /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/svn
```

Any advice from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Weep....

On ML Server the Apache configuration file is

/Library/Server/web/config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf

Not

/etc/appache2/httpd.conf

As I would have thought.

Once I read this it all made sense and started working.

https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.8/#apd9eb9f4ab-1377-47e6-a2c4-1311e25a74df

Sorry.